# How do I enable the ODT item in the export dispatcher permanently?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1, and my `org-export-dispatch` doesn't show "Export to ODT" by default. However, if I use `M-x org-odt-export-to-odt`, it works fine and the option is shown on the next dispatch.

How can I make the "Export to ODT" option permament without having to call `org-odt-export-to-odt` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org-export-backends` variable contains the backends that should always be available. In Emacs 24/Orgmode 8, it will be `(ascii html icalendar latex)`, which is why the ODT options aren't shown.

You have to customize the variable, e.g. `M-x customize-option RET org-export-backends RET`:

```
Org Export Backends:
[X]    ascii       Export buffer to ASCII format
[ ]    beamer      Export buffer to Beamer presentation
[X]    html        Export buffer to HTML format
[X]    icalendar   Export buffer to iCalendar format
[X]    latex       Export buffer to LaTeX format
[ ]    man         Export buffer to MAN format
[ ]    md          Export buffer to Markdown format
[ ]    odt         Export buffer to ODT format                <-----------
[ ]    org         Export buffer to Org format
[ ]    texinfo     Export buffer to Texinfo format
[ ] C  confluence  Export buffer to Confluence Wiki format
[ ] C  deck        Export buffer to deck.js presentations
[ ] C  freemind    Export buffer to Freemind mindmap format
[ ] C  groff       Export buffer to Groff format
[ ] C  koma-letter Export buffer to KOMA Scrlttrl2 format
[ ] C  RSS 2.0     Export buffer to RSS 2.0 format
[ ] C  s5          Export buffer to s5 presentations
[ ] C  taskjuggler Export buffer to TaskJuggler format
```

Keep in mind that the variable must be known, so you might need to enable `org-mode` at least once.

Note that [Emacs 25 provides ODT as default export](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/492d68c9369f228869644451042da8c035f8ebad). Unless you're stuck on Emacs 24 I recommend you to update your installation.

Comment: You can also `(require ox-odt)`. A strong +1 on the upgrade recommendation: org 8 is obsolete.